# On a mac, how do i get the screenshot to automatically have the timestamp on the resulting file name?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, screen-capture

some settings changed on my mac recently, where now every time I take a screenshot I have to edit the untitled file before it would have the timestamp, example filename: Screen Shot 2022-02-02 at 5.17.16 PM.png

How do I change this back to the way it was?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your first question! Can you share an example filename of how the screenshots without the timestamp?

Comment: Well normally, cmd+shift+3 adds a timestamp to the filename.

Comment: Yup, cmd+shift+3 works for me too.  How are you taking a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture "include-date" 1; killall SystemUIServer
```

in your terminal to reenable the date saving.

Comment: i added to this com.apple.screencapture, but when i take a screenshot i still get the image in the preview as untitled

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue, first launch the Screenshot.app on your Mac. I personally find it most efficient to use the Space-Command and simply type in 'screenshot', but there are other ways to locate the app as well. Once you open Screenshot.app, which you'll find at the bottom of your screen, look for the option labeled 'Options.' Click on this, and you'll be presented with a choice to save your screenshots either to the Desktop or to a different location. If you choose 'Other Location,' you can then select a specific folder where you wish to save your screenshots. This method ensures your screenshots are saved with timestamps. It's important to note that if you directly select an application like Preview as the save location, the naming convention is determined by the application itself. However, saving directly to a folder initially will retain the timestamp in the file name.

Comment: This works for me even if I keep Desktop as a target, so not sure it's required to change the location.